# Knockout's default template engine now when jQuery.tmpl is doomed

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

Does anybody know what will happen to Knockout's default template engine now when jQuery.tmpl [is not being actively developed or maintained anymore](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl)? Will Knockout switch to another default engine (which can be done quite easily, as [mentioned here in "Note 8")](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)? Or will it continue to use the pre-1.0.0 of jquery.tmpl as default, even though it's being dropped? Is there any candidate that is more probable to be the new default?

What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Steve Sandersons [Blog](http://blog.stevenshasderson.com/2011/07/22/review-open-source-components-used-in-learnknockoutjs/), who is author of knockoutjs, makes the following statement

*jQuery Templates (used internally by Knockout, and soon to be replaced with JsRender)*

So the thinking seems to be, Steve will do this to the beta 1.3 version before it is finally released.  Watch Steve's blog for an announcement. Also read the knockout forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/knockoutjs

There are a lot of us waiting for this.  Be patient.

Comment: In 1.3 beta, jsRender is already supported and more importantly it includes a native template engine, so you do not need to depend on any external engine.  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/

Comment: This is being discussed in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/D7QNpOrU9g0.  Short answer from @RPNiemeyer is that jsRender is not quite render for prime time yet.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm on 1.3.0-pre, and it's great to drop one more dependency (i.e. jquery.tmpl()). However, I feel as I must have missed something, as I find myself doing things like `<tr data-bind="foreach: items"><td data-bind="text: text"></td></tr>`. Is there something similar to the ${}-notation, so I can simply type `<td>${text}</td>`?

Comment: @Jacob - I'll be glad to help, but I don't understand the context of your question.  Can you put a sample jsfiddle together so I can see exactly what you are asking?

Comment: @photo_tom - Sorry for being unclear. What I'm asking for is a way to echo a variable's value in the template (like the old `${variable}` syntax). Here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jacobwod/y2YTS/1/ . Thanks!

Comment: I see what you are looking for. As I understand it, everything in the new native templates has to use a data-bind statement.  Also, the ${text} syntax is specific to jquery templates.  See http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/y2YTS/6/.  I had to wrap ${text} in a span tag.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I also got the same answer over at the forums, so it looks like you were right from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JsRender, as mentioned But you can also use native templates within KnockoutJs if you use 1.3 beta.

Comment: the reason that native templates were not discussed was because the question was explicitly about external template libraries.  That being said, I am a huge fan of the native templates.